# Querying multiple IDs at the same time, then combining into a single Observable

Tags: java, rx-java

I have a list of IDs that I need to query from a remote API. I want the entities to be queried from the API parallel (at the same time), and maintain the order of the ids in the list.

How do I achieve this with Observables?

```
Observable<String> strings = Observable.from(Arrays.asList(5, 4, 7, 2, 1)
                .stream()
                .map(Main::retrieve)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .flatMap(o -> o);
```

Using the above code snippet doesn't seem to guarantee the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that doing the collection from Java 8 `Stream` API inside of the `Observable.from(...)` is a good idea, as it is mixing two APIs with their own opinion of concurrency.

Instead I would make the call to `Main::retrieve` return an `Observable` (maybe using the `Observable.fromCallable`), which I would chain with the `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` operator call inside the `flatMap`.

`Schedulers.io()` uses a RxJava scheduler with a growing thread pool, for long running but CPU-light tasks (typically, IO).

Instead of `flatMap`, one can use `concatMapEager` if ordering **AND* parallelisation are both important. `concatMap` will maintain order by waiting for the first inner Observable to complete before triggering the second, etc...
`concatMapEager`, on the other hand, triggers all inner Observables then buffers those that return out of order, to replay them in order as soon as it is possible.

This is a minimal approach: triggering [ A B C ] and receiving in the [ A C B ] order means that "A" can be emitted right away (correct order), C is buffered until B arrives, and then is flushed from the buffer and emitted as well.

So the code would look like:

```
Observable<String> strings = Observable.from(Arrays.asList(5, 4, 7, 2, 1))
    //be efficient / parallel friendly but still retain order
    .concatMapEager(i -> 
        //Main's method has been converted to return an Observable
        retrieve(i)
        //retrieve will be executed in its own IO thread, so in parallel
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this behavior using `concatMapEager` instead of `flatMap`